# How to know precisely where a NullPointerException comes from?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, nullpointerexception

I'm writing some code in Java. 
I've got tons of classes that have subclasses that have subclasses ... You get it.
At some point, when running my code, I have a NullPointerException.
Eclipse tells me that it comes from a line of code that looks like :

```
Something1.Something2.Something3.Something4.Something5...
```

Where Something(n+1) is a field of Something(n).

My question is, do I have a way to know where is the NullPointerException exactly ?
I mean, any of the Something(n) could be null and cause the Exception when I try accessing one of its fields.

Thank you by advance,

Kal8578

Comment: You shouldn't be writing long chains like that in the first place. Even if you were using Java 14.

Comment: The code might not have been written by you. (As in - there might be people looking for answer to this question for valid reasons, it still deserves an answer)

Comment: Wow, thank you for the fast answers ! Unfortunately I'm using Java 8 (University project requires it), so I guess that I'll have to check every field one by one... Yes, this line of code is quite long, but I haven't found a simpler way to do things so far.

Comment: Then you should try. A class should be only accessing it's own fields, limiting such expressions just to one after a dot. Use method calls, and only talk to objects you know about. See [law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)

Comment: Well I completely agree on that, but on this particular project it's not really an option cause it's some sort of "this code is broken fix it" homework, so I'm not completely free of changing the way some things are implemented. I'll get my problem fixed by testing the fields one by one

Comment: This isn't an example of "subclasses", it's classes with properties (which are fine). Depending on the appropriate behavior if one of these is _allowed_ to be null, you could use an `Optional` chain, or if it's definitely a bug if there's a null, you can use a debugger to step through each link in the chain.

Answer (score 1):

You can get detailed info on NullPointerException only on JDK 14+.

- [See JEP 358 Helpful
  NullPointerException](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/358)
- [List of features included in
  JDK14](https://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk/14/)